# nodejs swagger-parameter setting question

Tags: node.js, swagger

front-end send data :

```
{
    "category": "1",
    "motion_list": [
        {
            "seq": "",
            "motion_id": "1",
            "motion_name": "input"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want send in swagger-ui and I'm setting follow:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/recipe/:
 *  post:
 *   summary: test
 *   description: 
 *   parameters:
 *    - name: category
 *      in: formData
 *      required: true
 *      default: 1
 *      type: string
 *    - name: motion_list
 *      in: formData
 *      type: array
 *      items:   
 *       type: object 
 *       format: json
 *       properties:
 *        seq:
 *         type: string
 *         example: ''
 *        motion_id: 
 *         type: string
 *         example: 1 
 *        motion_name:
 *         type: string
 *         example: input
 *   responses:
 *    '200':
 *     description: success
 */
```

but this fail because :
(node:31792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: motion_list.map is not a function

please help me swagger-parameter setting

Comment: Where are this parameters coming from? I don't understand what the api is expecting. Is that object supposed to in the body?

Comment: Also, OpenAPI 2.0 doesn't support objects and arrays of objects in `in: formData` parameters.